# EXT JS 5.1 Minified Core Frame work when developing

Tags: extjs, extjs5

When developing I want to use a a minified .js file of Ext JS 5.1 like they do on Sencha Fiddle. It looks like you can use the cdn link from Sencha but when I use this in the index file it fails.

Is there something I need to be doing in the bootstrap.js file to make it use just a link instead of the Ext Js 5 root folder?  I want to use the same link for multiple apps hosted on a server for an enterprise situation.

Also, the Chrome Dev Tools running super slow having to load each file. I want to use one minified file to make this useful again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not positive how you could use the [cdn file](https://extjs.cachefly.net/ext/gpl/5.1.0/build/ext-all-debug.js) referenced in the [sencha fiddle website](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home).  Adding that link directly to the app while using the microloader would cause errors. The microloader in extjs5 automatically figures out which files to load in the framework.

**However, you can achieve a similar goal of using a minified version of the extjs framework if you are using sencha cmd.**

[They detail how to setup your project to use the minified or developer copy of extjs5 instead of loading all the seperate files in this forum post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?290235-Sencha-Cmd-5.0.2-Beta-is-Now-Available)

Here are the changes to make to your project *documented to stack overflow in case that forum post is no longer available*:

**Step One**

make sure you are using a version of sencha cmd **greater than** `5.0.2`.
To determine your version of sencha cmd you can type the following in the command prompt:

```
sencha which
```

[If you have an older version of sencha cmd you can download the latest copy here](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download)

Thanks to Niederee for this little advice, do a sencha app upgrade on your app to make sure it's tied to the latest sencha command build

`sencha app upgrade`

**Step Two**

Adjust your `app.json` manifest file to load the `ext-all-rtl-debug.js` . Add this file to the `"js":[]` array in the file:

```
"js": [
        {
            "path": "${ext.dir}/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js"  // new default for generated apps
        },
        {
            "path": "app.js",
            "bundle": true
        }
    ],
```

You can also add sencha charts if they are required to get that minified build too:

```
        {
            "path": "${ext.dir}/packages/sencha-charts/build/sencha-charts-debug.js"
        },
```

*Optionally you can also adjust the cache preferences based on dev/production*
Add this additionally to the `app.json` file:

```
"development": {
        "loader": {
            "cache": true
        }
    },
    "production": {
        "loader": {
            "cache": "${build.timestamp}"
        }
    }
```

**Step Three**
In the command prompt run the following sencha command to refresh your application's bootstrap manifest.

```
sencha app refresh
```

Comment: it appears from initial testing you can also add sencha-charts this way too by referencing this path `"path": "${ext.dir}/packages/sencha-charts/build/sencha-charts-debug.js"`